# Scheduled posts to tumblr using the API

Tags: php, api, tumblr

For example, i want to post hourly posts to tumblr on the user's blog using PHP and the Tumblr's API.

I managed to make the application to do the posting with this flow:

- user comes on the site
- user logs in using oauth
- the post is posted

But now, i don't know what i need to store and how to access the user's profile everytime i need it, without the user coming to my site?

I read the documentation for the tumblr's official php library, but there're just those two lines about the auth:

```
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$client->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The **consumer key** and **consumer secret** are keys unique for the application you have registered with Tumblr.

If you have already done the things you list, then it sounds like you are already in possession of those keys. Preferably save them in the configuration file/database table of your application.

Every time a user authenticates using OAuth with Tumblr you will get two keys back that are **unique for that particular user**: the **token** and **token secret**.

In order to continue making API calls to Tumblr **as the user**, you need to [save their tokens in your database and associate them with the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458735/best-practice-for-storing-oauth-and-local-authentication-methods):

```
User table:
id int
username varchar
email varchar
password varchar

Tumblr profile table:
user_id int
token varchar
secret varchar
```